# Primefaces 5 - Dynamic p:menu issues

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menu, managed-bean

I'm new to Primefaces, and I'm following the [User Guide of Version 5.0](http://primefaces.org/documentation).
I've successfully built a static menu. Now I'm trying to build a very simple dynamic menu, basically copy-pasting the example on the user guide (page 294, if you are interested). But it's not working.

This is my XHTML page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>test-primefaces</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is my MenuBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBean {

   private MenuModel model;

   public MenuBean() {
       model = new DefaultMenuModel();
       //First submenu
       DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");
       DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
       item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
       item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
       firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
       model.addElement(firstSubmenu);

       //Second submenu
       DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Actions");
       item = new DefaultMenuItem("Save");
       item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");
       item.setCommand("#{menuBean.save}");
       item.setUpdate("messages");
       secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
       item = new DefaultMenuItem("Redirect");
       item.setIcon("ui-icon-search");
       item.setCommand("#{menuBean.redirect}");
       secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
       model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
   }

   public MenuModel getModel() {
       return model;
   }
}
```

The menu is not working, as I try to run the project (I'm using Netbeans) I get the following error

**Cannot find component with expression "messages" referenced from "j_idt5:j_idt6".**

I'm not able to undertand why I get it, and Google has not been able to help me.
Most doubts are about the annotation and the imports I used in MenuBean.java, since Netbeans tells me that annotations from "javax.faces.bean" will be deprecated in the next JSF version.

Another curious fact, in the XHTML page, if I change

`<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />` with `<p:megaMenu model="#{menuBean.model}" />`

I don't get the error, but the menu does not render the levle two menu items, I just see a menu with "Dynamic Submenu" and "Dynamic Actions", without any children entries.

What am I missing? I am willing to provide more information about my code/project, if necessary.

Comment: Check the programmatic menu in the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml. At the very least you need the part <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="false"/>

Comment: Hey, it was just that! Feel free to post an answer, and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Comment: the `item.setUpdate("messages");` is expecting to have a component called messages in order to pass the update..

Comment: And what about the oimports for the annotations, are they the correct ones? I assume so, since the menu is working now, but the imported libraries will be deprecated soon!

Comment: Since JSF 2.2 they're considered deprecated.. [see more](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/10/30/jsf-tip-30-migrate-your-managedbean-named-annotations)

Comment: So what annotations whould I use instead? I can use: "org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean", "javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean", "javax.annotation.ManagedBean".

Comment: for `@ManagedBean` you would use `@Named` instead, and the scopes are from cdi (javax.enterprise.context) except the `ViewScope` is `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it works better to check the Primefaces showcase first, then later one can always refer to the manual.

According to the example ["Programmatic menu"](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml) you need the part

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="false"/>
```

I guess thats also in fact what the error message is stating, that its missing.

About the annotations see the recommendation i.e. [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/10/30/jsf-tip-30-migrate-your-managedbean-named-annotations). Since JSF 2.2 it is recommended to move from JSF beans to CDI beans.

Answer (score 2):

**Cannot find component with expression "messages" referenced from "j_idt5:j_idt6"** mean that it can't find component with **id="message"** from component with **id="j_idt5:j_idt6"** that have property **update="message"**, in your code is item.setUpdate("messages");

another solution is to remove item.setUpdate("messages"); if you dont want to update anything, or you add a component with id message in you page if you want to update the message.